# Using telecomManager with our custom protocol

Tags: android, video, phone-call, android-phone-call

I`m trying to implement interconnection with telecom service with this guide: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom/

I'm are already can show my own fullscreen incoming call UI without Telecom service, make and receive video calls. All, that I want to do with Telecomservice, is just tell Android OS, that our application is starting/stopping video call in particular moment, and receive call holded/unholded events from other calling apps.

The main problems are:

1) addNewIncomingCall in case of incoming call does nothing: onCreateIncomingConnection callback not fired (even onCreate callback of mine ConnectionService not fired at all). Why connection service is not started?

2) in case of outgoing call placeCall tries to open system calling app with our user id, call it as phone or SIP number. Can I use placeCall without system UI?

Or, if I just want to inform system about video call, I can use other option than TelecomService?

Connection created as follows:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        connection?.connectionProperties = Connection.PROPERTY_SELF_MANAGED
    }
    connection?.connectionCapabilities = Connection.CAPABILITY_HOLD and Connection.CAPABILITY_SUPPORT_HOLD
    connection?.setVideoState(VideoProfile.STATE_BIDIRECTIONAL)
```

Placing call:

```
val telecomService = context.getSystemService(Context.TELECOM_SERVICE) as TelecomManager
                    try {
                        val uri = Uri.fromParts(PhoneAccount.SCHEME_SIP, teacherInfo.name, null)
                        telecomService.placeCall(uri, Bundle.EMPTY)
                    } catch (e: Throwable) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
```

Receiving call:

```
val telecomService = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.TELECOM_SERVICE) as TelecomManager
                      try {
                          Log.d("VideoCOnnection", "addNewIncomingCall")
                          telecomService.addNewIncomingCall(CallUtils.getAccountConnection(telecomService), Bundle.EMPTY)
                      } catch (e: Throwable) {
                          Log.d("VideoCOnnection", "crash")
                          e.printStackTrace()
                      }


@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
fun getAccountConnection(teleconManager: TelecomManager) : PhoneAccountHandle? {
    return if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        val enabledAccounts = teleconManager.callCapablePhoneAccounts
        for(account in enabledAccounts) {
            if(account.componentName.className.equals(BindTelecomService::class.java.canonicalName)) {
                return account
            }
        }
        return null
    } else
        null
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/pranksterN1/TComTest https://stackoverflow.com/users/4466771/prankstern1 posted this example, which worked, but I still can not find, what's wrong with my code:)
Additional Services, such as CallService from example is used for connection listening only, and can be replaced with GreenRobot's eventbus or Rx for simplification

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want to implement the app with [self-managed connection service](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom/selfManaged).

Check that you have permissions:

- MANAGE_OWN_CALLS
- READ_CALL_LOG
- READ_PHONE_STATE

Register the phone account with CAPABILITY_SELF_MANAGED.

```java
final String phoneAccountLabel = "myPhoneApp";

ComponentName connectionServiceName = new ComponentName(context.getApplicationContext(), TcService.class);
accountHandle = new PhoneAccountHandle(connectionServiceName, phoneAccountLabel);

PhoneAccount phoneAccount = telecom.getPhoneAccount(accountHandle);
if (phoneAccount == null) {
    PhoneAccount.Builder builder = PhoneAccount.builder(accountHandle, phoneAccountLabel);
    builder.setCapabilities(PhoneAccount.CAPABILITY_SELF_MANAGED);
    phoneAccount = builder.build();
    telecom.registerPhoneAccount(phoneAccount);
}
```

When you add new incoming or outgoing calls, you must add extra EXTRA_PHONE_ACCOUNT_HANDLE.

```java
Uri uri = generateCallUri();
extras.putParcelable(TelecomManager.EXTRA_PHONE_ACCOUNT_HANDLE, accountHandle);
telecom.addNewIncomingCall(accountHandle, extras);
```

**Update**: [there is an example](https://github.com/pranksterN1/TComTest)

Comment: Thanks, now it at least not showing system's call UI, but I still can not place call with our hexademical user id: system showing "incorrect number" dialog. How to properly create call URI?

Comment: Something like Uri.parse("tel:12345") but I don't think it really matters.
I noticed that different phone models have different behavior with this API. Looks like some of them do not implement it correctly. For instance I cannot make my app work properly on Samsung devices, but with Nexus or Pixel I don't experience any troubles.

Comment: Also, if you need to add your data to the call, it's better to put it in extras and then fetch it in your ConnectionService.

Comment: Still no effect at Nexus 6P: no callback in my ConnectionService implementation is invoked, and no error in logs:( AccountHandle creation is identical:  https://pastebin.com/tb88c6ch

Comment: I made an example for you, [check it out](https://github.com/pranksterN1/TComTest)

Comment: @pranksterN1 what should be the placeCall uri in case of VoIP calls?

Comment: @tronku
It should be URI with scheme tel or sip. 
But don't put emergency numbers there as some phones tend to make real gsm calls to emergency services in this case.